# Bash expanding $* or $@ to a function

Tags: bash

I don't typically ask questions & help people, however I have written a relatively large bash script @ currently at about 1700 lines.  I utilize a multitude of functions to push data from one function to another using "$*".  The entire script does squat until "$1" is processed in a case statement at the very end of of the script:

```
case "$1" in
  -s|--scan) VersionDump "$@"; DumpArray "$*"; exit 0;;
  -t|--test) VersionDump "$@"; Virtual "$*"; exit 0;;
  -e|--erase) VersionDump "$@"; Clear "$*"; exit 0;;
  -l|--load) Loadit "$*"; exit 0;;
  -i|--info) ThumbInfo "$*"; exit 0;;
  -h|--help|-\?) Help "$2"; exit 0;;
  -v|--version) VersionDump "$@"; exit 0;;
  *) Help; exit 0;;
esac
```

I guess it is probably best to understand what we are [dealing](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=9610) with, there is more information on my forum.  I have taken stabs at trying to get "$*" as well as "$@" to drop back to an array with failure at each pass.  I have written "DEBUGGING" code on each function so I can analyze as commands are passed from function to function if the word "debug" is detected in the command line:

```
# Optional switch - useful for me and the end user.
DEBUG=$(echo "$*" | grep -i "debug")
if [[ "$DEBUG" ]]; then
    Center "${txtred}DEBUG INFORMATION"
    printf "DEBUGGING Function:\t%s\n" "$FUNCNAME"
    printf "PASSED TO FUNCTION *:\t%s\n" "${@}"
    echo -e "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4 5:$5 6:$6 7:$7 8:$8"
    echo -en "Caller [LINE] / APP: "
    caller
    FullBar
    echo -en "${txtrst}"
fi
```

I am totally re-writing the entire script to remove dependencies.  Yes, I know I am not providing the entire piece of code. I am certain there will be questions.  The entire script has been [ShellChecked](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and 0 of the errors, yes there are a few such as variables I no longer use etc.  Nothing I consider deter-mental.

Things are not always as they seem (Command Passed):

```
./ultimate-edition-thumbos_1.1.4_all/bin/thumbos --load ../wip/ultimate-edition-5.0-x64-lite-xfce.iso sdg debug
```

Results:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ DEBUG INFORMATION ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
DEBUGGING Function: Loadit
PASSED TO FUNCTION *:   --load ../wip/ultimate-edition-5.0-x64-lite-xfce.iso sdg debug
1:--load ../wip/ultimate-edition-5.0-x64-lite-xfce.iso sdg debug 2: 3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8:
Caller [LINE] / APP: 1688 ./ultimate-edition-thumbos_1.1.4_all/bin/thumbos
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

Where is my $2 etc. ?  Am I do something wrong?

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/38906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$*"` expands to a single word.

You can't use it anywhere you need your arguments as individual words. That's what `"$@"` is for.

That debugging output indicates (both directly and indirectly) that you passed your arguments to the `Loadit` function as `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.

Which, as can be seen from the earlier snippet `-l|--load) Loadit "$*"; exit 0;;` you did.

Don't do that. Use `Loadit "$@"`.

Rule of thumb is that `"$@"` is almost always what you want (unless you need a single word).

---

Just FYI the "indirectly" bit of my comment above is that `printf` repeats the format string for arguments when they don't all fit.

So you get

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\n' foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

but

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz
foo
bar
baz
```

so when your debugging output only contained a *single* `PASSED TO FUNCTION *:\t%s\n` line it was telling you that it only saw one argument.

Comment: I'd say you are right, however I will have to re-write the debug code as well:
    DEBUGGING Function: Loadit
PASSED TO FUNCTION *: --load
PASSED TO FUNCTION *: ../wip/ultimate-edition-5.0-x64-lite-xfce.iso
PASSED TO FUNCTION *: sdg
PASSED TO FUNCTION *: debug
1:--load 2:../wip/ultimate-edition-5.0-x64-lite-xfce.iso 3:sdg 4:debug 5: 6: 7: 8:
Caller [LINE] / APP: 1688 ./ultimate-edition-thumbos_1.1.4_all/bin/thumbos

for loop, got to love it when code just gets longer and longer lol THANKS!  ShellCheck should have made that suggestion, rater then tell me $[star] is unacceptable use quotes.

Comment: Yup, that's the FYI bit at the end. For that line you *do* want the single string so using `"$*"` is appropriate. And that's basically the only time you want it in my experience.

Comment: I tried to up you, but It says don't have 15 points, I have 40 for helping people those don't count I guess and the thousands for helping people on my forum. ;)

Comment: If this solved the problem then you should accept the answer (checkmark). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for a full explanation of how this works.

Comment: I did, it said I had insufficient points. I had 40 for solving others issues, now 16 for asking a question.  Finally got the up arrow to work.  How do I accept your answer.  Like I said, I do not come on here to ask questions.

Comment: "$*" is still used in a large chunk of my code, FYI.  I don't want the end user to have to care --load blah.iso sdj or --load sdj blah.iso.  Thanks to you however I can rebuild vars in each front of the function.

Comment: You *can't* rebuild filenames with spaces, etc. You *need* the user to pass them to you correctly. Doing anything else is asking for trouble and is just not a good idea. The shell has the tools to have things handled correctly. Use them. Don't (ab)use them.